# Logitech M185 Wireless Mouse Not Fully Functional After Upgrading to Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, mouse, peripherals

I upgraded from Fedora 29 to Fedora 31 and now my logitech M185 mouse is only partially functional. The middle and right buttons do nothing, and the left button appears to only be able to make a window active but can do nothing within a window. For example, I cannot click on any links in a web browser, I cannot highlight text, nor can I even drag or resize a window. The kernel is 5.5.7-200.fc31 and I am using fedora release 31. I tried booting with older kernels but it does not change anything. The mouse worked just fine with plug-and-play behavior on fedora 29. Moreover, I have a logitech wireless keyboard that seems to be working just fine after the upgrade.

I have searched the web for any description of a similar problem, but have had no luck.

Comment: don't search the internet for the problem ... instead, search for how to configure the mouse

Comment: @jsotola I don't find anything that helps when searching for mouse configuration. The mouse "works", but it appears that no mouse events are passed to the active window.